# How to load Fantom5 dataset? CAge analysis

Tags: r

Does anyone familiar with CAGE analysis? I am using the CAGEr packages to deal with the Fantom5 dataset.

However, I couldn't load Fantom5 data. I think the reason why is either I didn't find the right package name or there's no packages like Fantom3 and 4.

for Fantom3 and 4, Just simply using biocLite

```
biocLite("FANTOM3and4CAGE")
```

Then I am able to do

```
library(FANTOM3and4CAGE)

data(FANTOMhumanSamples)
```

Any one deal with this dataset before?

Thank you very much

Comment: It is included with `CAGEr` according to this [manual](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/CAGEr/man/CAGEr.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. I did install that packages and did use the the code as the manual said, which is <data(FANTOMmouseSamples). However, the error information is Warning message:
In data(FANTOM5humanSamples) : data set ‘FANTOM5humanSamples’ not found

Answer (score 0):

I emailed the developer of this package, who is really really nice by the way.

It's because The FANTOM5humanSamples and the functionality for fetching the FANTOM5 data are available from CAGEr package version 1.6., which will be installed by Bioconductor version 2.14 in the newest version of R. If you are using slightly older version of R it by default uses Bioconductor version 2.12. and installs old version of CAGEr (1.2.9.)